# how to declare IntPtr in iOS Binding project on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-frameworks, intptr, xamarin-binding

I'm trying to connect iOS Framework to Xamarin. (I've never experienced Xamarin.)
so I did succeed to bind iOS Framework.

also I declare the protocol DownloadDelegate

when I bind my framework, DownloadDelegate is inherited iNativeObject by Xamarin.

and I made the class <kbd>BookDownloadHelper : DownloadDelegate { }</kbd>
It requires to declare Handle <kbd>public IntPtr Handle => IntPtr.zero</kbd>

when I call download() on Xamarin, Xamarin app crash due to Handle

```
 public class SampleBridgeiOS 
 {
    private BookDownloadHelper helper = new BookDownloadHelper();
    public void closeBook()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("close book");
    }

    public void donwload(String pk)
    {

        var info = new DownloadBookInfo();

        info.Author = "test";
        info.Title = "test";

        ViewerBookManager.DownloadBook(info, this.helper); // ViewerBookManaer is the class of iOS framework
    }
}
```

BookDownloadHelper

```
public class BookDownloadHelper : IBookDownloadDelegate
{

    public IntPtr Handle => IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

DownloadBook function

```
public static void DownloadBook (DownloadBookInfo info, IBookDownloadDelegate @delegate)
{
    IntPtr nonNullHandle = NativeObjectExtensions.GetNonNullHandle   ((INativeObject)(object)info, "info");
    IntPtr nonNullHandle2 = NativeObjectExtensions.GetNonNullHandle ((INativeObject)@delegate, "delegate");
    Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (class_ptr, Selector.GetHandle ("downloadBook:delegate:"), nonNullHandle, nonNullHandle2);
}
```

I don't know how to declare Handle.
please help me...